# Meteor: use babel optional chaining plugin

Tags: meteor, babeljs

How to use babel **babel-plugin-transform-optional-chaining** package in Meteor?

I've created **.babelrc file** in the root directory with following code:

```
{
  "plugins": ["transform-optional-chaining"]
}
```

But it's not working.

Comment: What is  your question? What isn't working?

Comment: @Mikkel Its simple. How to use babel-plugin-transform-optional-chaining package in meteor ?

Comment: You said you wanted `transform-optional-chaining` but you added `syntax-optional-chaining`. Those are two different things, is this just a mistake on your part?

Comment: @loganfsmyth . I've corrected my mistake. So how i can use that package in meteor?

Comment: see here https://forums.meteor.com/t/add-babel-plugin-syntax-optional-chaining/39683/8

Answer (score 0):

Run:

```
meteor update --release 1.6.1
meteor npm i @babel/core @babel/runtime @babel/preset-stage-1
```

Create .babelrc:

```
{ "presets": [ "@babel/preset-stage-1" ] }
```

And you are ready to go!

Comment: I'm getting this error when updating from Meteor 1.5.4:

`=> Errors while initializing project:`
`While selecting package versions:`
`error: Conflict: Constraint babel-compiler@6.18.1 is not satisfied by babel-compiler 7.0.0-rc161.1.`
`Constraints on package "babel-compiler":`
`* babel-compiler@~7.0.0-rc161.1 <- top level`
`* babel-compiler@7.0.0-rc161.1 <- ecmascript 0.10.0-rc161.1`
`* babel-compiler@6.18.1 <- unomi:minifier-js 2.0.0 <- unomi:standard-minifier-js 2.0.3`

I'm not sure to understand what I'm supposed to do...

Comment: try it now with new release of Meteor 1.6.1